# Convert string to list and i want to insert value to list

Tags: python

```
Str="123ffb06789ff000000"
List=list[str]
print(list) 
List.insert(0, "ma") 
print(list)
```

After converting string to list I need to insert value

Comment: It appears you've perhaps typed your code in using a browser that's automatically capitalizing for you, and without code formatting. Can you please show us the exact code you're working with and the exact output/error you're seeing?

Comment: This code does not print None -- it raises an exception.  Please update the question to post your real code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). The code shown here does not make sense, and it's hard to understand the description of the problem.

Comment: You have typo errors. Str=[123ffb06789ff000000]
List=list[Str]
print(List) 
List.insert(0, "ma") 
print(List)

Comment: list['123ffb06789ff000000']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\supra\Documents\python3 dummy\testing_dummny.py", line 4, in <module>
    List.insert(0, "ma")
TypeError: descriptor 'insert' for 'list' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object

Comment: You haven't said what your ultimate goal is. But on the off chance that you're just trying to arrive at a modified string, you could do `new_string = 'ma' + string` and skip the list conversion entirely.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You have some faults with the code you've provided, but I've fixed them and this should work:

```py
my_string = "123ffb06789ff000000"
my_list = list(my_string)    # This was changed later in an edit.
my_list.insert(0, "ma")

print(my_list) 

# OUTPUT
# ['ma', '1', '2', '3', 'f', 'f', 'b', '0', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'f', 'f', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

Comment: Don't need to use List Comprehension for making this char. list.

Comment: @DanielHao Ah yes, been a little while since I used Python. Your answer is certainly more Pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to run `this code` (correct some typo/case)?
Try to see if that's what you want?

```
string = "123ffb06789ff000000"  # avoid using built-in `str`
lst = list(string)     # `list` is a constructor so we need list(str)

lst.insert(0, "ma")    # avoid using Capital letter as variable name
print(lst)  # ['ma', '1', '2', '3', 'f', 'f', 'b' .....]
```